# [Adyen][POS][Local integration] Send metadata to the terminal

Tags: adyen

Currently, I try to send **SaleToAcquirerData** **metadata** to the terminal when the order to sync to Adyen Backend, I have checked at Adyen Backend but don't see **metadata** and my webhook cannot receive **metadata**

I need to send *metadata* to the terminal and receive **metadata** at my webhook

Comment: Hey there. Could you please provide extra information as to what you mean with "I don't see metadata" and "cannot receive metadata"?  Is the payload empty, are you receiving the webhook? Can you provide a sample output of a received webhook by any chance?

Answer (score 0):

In this answer, I expect that you

- Already receive webhooks events and that your webhook is well configured
- That you receive core data from webhook events but that the POS related additional data is missing

Have you activated the POS additional data for this specific webhook?
You can do it in the Customer Area, Developer -> Webhook, select your webhook and then "Additional settings".

The UI looks like this :

[image]

Save, and exit. Your future webhooks events should contain POS metadata. Please note that you may still receive some events without the metadata that you except, because they were already generated at the time they were created.

EDIT :  In case you want to use the API for this, you can also [PATCH the existing webhook](https://docs.adyen.com/api-explorer/#/ManagementService/v1/patch/merchants/%7BmerchantId%7D/webhooks/%7BwebhookId%7D) with [additional settings](https://docs.adyen.com/development-resources/webhooks/additional-settings) using the new Management API.

---

While waiting for extra information, your question may be understood another way : You want to access the [metadata field of the additional data section of a webhook event](https://docs.adyen.com/api-explorer/#/Webhooks/v1/post/AUTHORISATION__reqParam_notificationItems-additionalData-metadata).

In that case, these metadata fields should be submitted at the time of payment in the [POST /payments](https://docs.adyen.com/api-explorer/#/CheckoutService/v69/post/payments__reqParam_metadata) request.

You can find more information about this in the [Webhooks documentation](https://docs.adyen.com/development-resources/webhooks/additional-settings).

Comment: Can u help me by the channel chatting?